# Travis fails to build Android project, no local.properties

Tags: android, gradle, travis-ci

Here is the thing. I've built my project on the Travis CI several times, but got the same problem every time.

The error log:

`What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'LiteReader'.
/home/travis/build/Mindjet/LiteReader/local.properties (No such file or directory)`

It's true that the project I uploaded has **no local.properties**, I've excluded it because it contains information specific to local configuration.

It's my .travis.yml

```
language: android
cache: bundler

android:
  components:
    - tools
    - build-tools-25.0.2
    - android-25
    - extra-android-m2repository
    - extra-android-support

before_install:
  - chmod +x gradlew

script:
      ./gradlew checkstyle build
```

How can I solve this problem? Please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

A bit late to the party, but I ran into the same issue and found a simpler solution:

```
before_script:
  - touch local.properties
```

This will create the file, before running the script, but without the need  to create and add a "fake" file into your project.

Comment: Works like a charm. I don't know why it doesn't treat the non existence similar to a blank file

Comment: please mention the fact that if they hide keys in local.properties use something like "touch local.properties | echo "YOUR_KEY_NAME_IN_LOCAL.PROPERTIES" >> local.properties | ... so on and so on. just for future people to benefit from.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem with **GitHub Actions CI**

The issue is /local.properties (No such file or directory) and it is solved in this way:

```
- name: Touch local properties
  run: touch local.properties

- name: Add Api Key
  run: echo "apiKey=\"\"" >> local.properties
```

This will create the file and add your variables (ex: empty API key)  to it Then add the code to run the test and it will pass without errors.

```
- name: Run Tests
  run: ./gradlew test
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using CircleCI instead of Travis but I had the same problem :) 
I fixed it like [this](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/android-build-failed-file-not-found/5474), it should do the trick for you, if you can do something like that in Travis (I don't see a reason why you couldn't).

TL;DR

1. Create the "local.properties.ci" in the same directory of "local.properties"
2. Put fake data in it so the CI build can pass
3. Add it to Git
4. Add the code below in circle.yml:

`checkout:
  post:
    - cp local.properties.ci local.properties`

Comment: Please don't just lik to another website that contains the solution. Always summarize the solution inside your own answer. You can still link to the resource in the end.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it makes sense. I edited the answer :)