# Travis CI cannot find local.properties

Tags: android, travis-ci

The error is `local.properties (No such file or directory)`.

My `yml` file:

```
language: android

android:
  components:
    - platform-tools
    - build-tools-27.1.1
    - build-tools-27.0.3
    - android-27

before_install:
  - yes | sdkmanager "platforms;android-27"
```

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42827701/9344497) solution and didn't work. I can't upload my `local.properties` because it has local variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer on [this](https://github.com/workarounds/typography/issues/4) thread.

Add this code end of the `build.gradle`

```
if (project.rootProject.file('local.properties').exists()) {
    apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/installv1.gradle'
    apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/bintrayv1.gradle'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue and found a simpler solution:

```
before_script:
  - touch local.properties
```

This will create the file, before running the script, but without the need  to create and add a "fake" file into your project.

Originally posted at https://stackoverflow.com/a/50113175/532368.